How do I tell whether bean seeds are viable?
I was saving a few pods of French green beans in my garden for seeds.  They are the ones I missed I harvesting.  The pods are still green but the seeds inside are big and firm.
I picked them this afternoon because there is frost predicted.  I was hoping to let them go a little longer.
How do I tell whether they will be viable for planting next spring?  Is there some way I can test them?

Do google "germination test". Takes 1 minute to setup and 2 weeks to wait out.

If the pods aren't dry as a crisp the seeds will not grow - you should have left them for longer.

I pulled them because the internet seems to suggest that they wouldn't have survived  last week's early first frost. I think they are headed for the compost heap
